# Deploy GAE server through a deploy script without using App launcher

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

Is there a way I can deploy the GAE server without using the GAE launcher. I would like to deploy my application through terminal/command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool is called appcfg.py or appcfg.sh for java.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp or https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp